# Django management commands when using AWS Fargate

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

I have deployed a Django application using the AWS Fargate service. It is so far working good, but I am wondering if there is any quick / easy way to interact with the Django management commands? What would be the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could add a bash file running the management commands to the DockerFile entrypoint `ENTRYPOINT ["/code/script_with_command.sh"]` and push the updated image.

Comment: Yes, I'll do that for the migrate and collectstatic commands. However, I would also like to run one of commands now and then (Having custom Django management commands). Or maybe this is the wrong way doing it?

Comment: have a look at this https://github.com/azavea/django-ecsmanage FYI i havent tried it myself